# How to scroll content blocks left and right in css

Tags: css, horizontal-scrolling

I am building a scrolling frame on a web page.

The frame is `width: 90%` of the page-width.

I have a total of 7 blocks but I only want to show 5 at a time with a left & right button for scrolling left and right. Each block is `width: 18%`

What are the minimum css styles I should consider to get starting building this?

Comment: Is my solution OK for you?

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: Sorry...took a break and just returned @CommercialSuicide

Answer (score 1):

> What are the minimum css styles I should consider to get starting
>   building this?

Is this what are you trying to achieve?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  padding: 16px 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  text-align: start;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(90vw / 5);
  text-align: start;
  float: left;
}

.content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc((90vw / 5) * 7);
  text-align: start;
}

.buttons-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90vw;
  height: calc(100px - 16px);
}

.left-button,
.right-button {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  top: calc(50% - 15px);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.left-button {
  left: 0;
}

.right-button {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="buttons-wrapper">
    <div class="left-button">L</div>
    <div class="right-button">R</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content" style="background-color: red"></div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: orange"></div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: green"></div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: lightblue"></div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: blue"></div>
    <div class="content" style="background-color: violet"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this is very, very close. What I need to figure out is making the left and right scroll buttons reveal the blue and the violet @CommercialSuicide. Thanks.